# How to delete column in sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I used this instruction https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html

still when I cut it only cuts 2 chars instead of the whole column of "00:00" why ?

[image]

Comment: i think it sees the colon as a seperator

Comment: add to your selection by using the ctrl button

Comment: you may be interested in this https://github.com/FichteFoll/InsertDates Its a plugin that allows you to format the date - if you format the date beforehand to not come up with the 00:00 you can save yourself the hassle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't selected a column. If you look carefully, you've only selected the `00` on the first line, and the rest of them are highlighted because they match the current selection. Make sure you are using the correct key/mouse sequence for your operating system from the documentation you linked to, then select *the entire column*, not just the first two characters.

Answer (score 3):

While holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>↓</kbd> until you reach the end of the column. It will clone your cursor down the column. Then, use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> key to select text. Once selected do whatever you want with it.